# Windows 7 System Hang issue

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Toshiba Laptop. I recently did a fresh installation of Windows 7.

I have been noticing, don't know exactly since when, that the system just freezes when I am working. The only way is to do a hard reset.

I don't know if some software is causing it. Is there any way, through log messages, to find out the reason for the system hang? If I can pinpoint the issue to particular software, system upgrade or something, I can revert back the changes.

Answer (score 1):

It has happened to me too; even with a brand-new win-7 home premium - it still froze. Checking with 'hijackthis' does give you more details about what is running and hence, what might cause the freezing.
Also: under CMD type msconfig (right-click to execute as admin) and see what programs squeezed themselves in the boot-up sequence without true need; uncheck all suspicious or unnecessary (like HPupdate etc) and restart.

Answer (score 0):

If your run out of options after looking into logs/events you could try to force System Crash from keyboard when this happens and then analyze the dump* with debugger (`windbg` for example- link to debugging tools here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

*You wold proably want to set dump type to `kernel`, you can set it in `System->Advanced->Startup and Recovery`

How to enable keyboard initiated crash is described in details here: [Forcing a system crash from keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Main points:

> You must ensure the following three settings before the keyboard can
> cause a system crash:
>
> If you wish a crash dump file to be written, you must enable such dump
> files, choose the path and file name, and select the size of the dump
> file. For more information, see Enabling a Kernel-Mode Dump File.
>
> With PS/2 keyboards, you must enable the keyboard-initiated crash in
> the registry. In the registry key
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters,
> create a value named CrashOnCtrlScroll, and set it equal to a
> REG_DWORD value of 0x01.
>
> With USB keyboards, you must enable the keyboard-initiated crash in
> the registry. In the registry key
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters,
> create a value named CrashOnCtrlScroll, and set it equal to a
> REG_DWORD value of 0x01.
>
> You must restart the system for these settings to take effect.
>
> After this is completed, the keyboard crash can be initiated by using
> the following hotkey sequence: Hold down the rightmost CTRL key, and
> press the SCROLL LOCK key twice.
>
> (...)
>
> **Limitations**
>
> It is possible for a system to freeze in such a way that the keyboard
> shortcut sequence will not work. However, this should be a very rare
> occurrence. Using the keyboard shortcut sequence to initiate a crash
> will work even in many instances where CTRL+ALT+DELETE does not work.
>
> Forcing a system crash from the keyboard does not work if the computer
> stops responding at a high interrupt request level (IRQL). This
> limitation exists because the Kbdhid.sys driver, which allows the
> memory dump process to run, operates at a lower IRQL than the
> i8042prt.sys driver.